# Having "APPLICATION FAILED TO START" error on Spring Boot startup

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, vault

I'm developing an API on Spring Boot using Vault and Mongo, but it refuses to start.

```
2022-09-07 13:58:56.510  WARN 23885 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultReactiveBootstrapConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.vault-org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultProperties': Could not bind properties to 'VaultProperties' : prefix=spring.cloud.vault, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
2022-09-07 13:58:56.513  INFO 23885 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-07 13:58:56.521 ERROR 23885 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
```

**EDIT: I think the problem is that Spring Boot tries to use javax and jakarta at the same time according to this part of the error:
`nested exception is javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found.`. Is this a normal behavior?**

Comment: please add you `pom.xml` to the question

Comment: Set `debug=true`or `debug: true` in your application.properties or application.yml depending on what you’re using to see the error. The hibernate warning is a red herring.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @AndrewThomas pom.xml added (I tested with and without commented dependencies).

Comment: @Strelok debug: true set but error still remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `hibernate-validator` 6 and `spring-boot-starter-validation` solved the problem.
Thing to know: hibernate-validator < 7 uses Javax, hibernate-validator => 7 uses Jakarta.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I think you don't need the `hibernate-validator` if you import the `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Answer (score -1):

Consider to bypass the problem: try to add `compile 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'` to your build.gradle, and `@Bean public MongoClient embeddedMongoClient()` to return a dummy Mongo client during the Init phase.

The real mongo Url could be fetched (and used) from the Vault later, during run time, once required, via a customized extends of spring-data-mongodb's MongoDbFactory.

Comment: Hi, this project uses maven. I don't think the problem is triggered by Mongo itself. I rewrited the app from scratch by adding one by one my features in the new one and everything is working on my machine. Now I still have the error in the dockerized deployed version.
In the error Spring boot triggers a javax exception claiming jakarta is not present... I think this is the problem. Why javax wants jakarta to be present?
However I tried to add javax validation, jakarta validation, etc. in the pom but that doesnt change anything.